# java.io.IOException: bt socket is not in listen state [Android Marshmallow]

Tags: java, android, android-6.0-marshmallow, google-glass, android-bluetooth

I am trying to establish a connection between nexus 5(Android 6+) and Google Glass.
Client side code to connect:

```
try {
    bluetoothSocket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                BluetoothParametersHolder.uuids[0]);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

//In a thread
bluetoothSocket.connect();
```

Server side code:

```
 mmServerSocket = bluetoothAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(
                BluetoothParametersHolder.NAME, BluetoothParametersHolder.uuids[0]);

//In a thread
socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
```

Using https://github.com/vicmns/BluetoothGlass as a reference.
The problem I'm facing is that immediately after the accept() returns, connection gets disconnect with the following error:

> 02-15 16:20:42.769 2163-2414/? E/bt_btif_sock_rfcomm:
>   find_rfc_slot_by_id unable to find RFCOMM slot id: 51
>       02-15 16:20:43.761 8345-8361/? W/System.err: java.io.IOException: bt socket is not in listen state
>       02-15 16:20:43.762 8345-8361/? W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.accept(BluetoothSocket.java:453)
>       02-15 16:20:43.763 8345-8361/? W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket.accept(BluetoothServerSocket.java:158)
>       02-15 16:20:43.763 8345-8361/? W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket.accept(BluetoothServerSocket.java:144)
>       02-15 16:20:43.763 8345-8361/? W/System.err:     at knowles.com.serverapp.handlers.BluetoothConnectionHandler.doInBackground(BluetoothConnectionHandler.java:41)
>       02-15 16:20:43.763 8345-8361/? W/System.err:     at knowles.com.serverapp.handlers.BluetoothConnectionHandler.doInBackground(BluetoothConnectionHandler.java:16)
>       02-15 16:20:43.763 8345-8361/? W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
>       02-15 16:20:43.764 8345-8361/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>       02-15 16:20:43.764 8345-8361/? W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
>       02-15 16:20:43.764 8345-8361/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>       02-15 16:20:43.764 8345-8361/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>       02-15 16:20:43.782 8345-8361/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

I am new to Bluetooth and Glass. Any help is really appreciated. Didn't get much help from the existing posts.
All I'm trying here is to send a 'hello' message from client(Glass) to server(Mobile).

Answer (score 1):

Looking inside the framework code, we can find following:

```
if (mSocketState != SocketState.LISTENING)
    throw new IOException("bt socket is not in listen state");
```

Clearly the method `accept()` throws exception if the socket is not in the state `LISTENING`.

In most of the cases this happens if the instance of `BluetoothServerSocket` is **already closed**. Make sure the `BluetoothServerSocket` is not closed before trying to accept connections.